# How to get returned value from Navigator.pop using Navigator.restorable?

Tags: flutter

Currently my original way of getting values between screen using Navigator.pop was like this:

Second screen goes back to home screen and passes a boolean:

```
Navigator.pop(context, false);
```

Home screen awaiting for the Navigator and capturing the value:

```
var bookmarked = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CorePage()),
);
```

However I've recently started using restorable to restore states when the app randomly closes such as:

```
static Route<void> _staticGoToCoreWorkout(context, arguments) =>
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CorePage());

Navigator.restorablePush(context, _staticGoToCoreWorkout);
```

The problem I'm having is that something like this doesn't work anymore:

```
var bookmarked = Navigator.restorablePush(context, _staticGoToCoreWorkout);
```

How can I go about getting the boolean value (or any value really) that's passed from the Navigator.pop back to the previous screen when I'm using restorable?

**UPDATED:**

Adding await doesn't yield results either. It will always run pass the code.

```
var bookmarked = await Navigator.restorablePush(context, _staticGoToCoreWorkout);
```

Comment: Take a look at [RestorableRouteFuture](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorableRouteFuture-class.html)